# Javascript to change background of element with id

Tags: javascript, html

I have a file upload element:

```
<input type="file" name='image1' id='image1'>
```

Then i have a button:

```
<button onclick="addphotos()">Add photos</button>
```

The addphotos() function is:

```
function addphotos() {
  var file1 = document.getElementById('image1').files[0];
  var img1=file1.name.split(/(\\|\/)/g).pop();
  var pic1 = "url(" + file1 + ")";
  document.getElementById("right").style.backgroundImage=pic1;
}
```

As far as I know, the last line's syntax should be correct but I think I am missing something there. Reference for last line syntax - http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_js_background-image

EDIT: Its not working. No image is being put on the cube's face.

Comment: are you getting an error? Is it not doing what you want?

Comment: No error. It's just that no image is getting put on the cube's face.

Comment: What does a `console.log(pic1)` give you?

Comment: And what is `right`?

Comment: I'm just wondering, when you go to inspect-element (ctrl+shift+i) are there any red X errors you can click on? Usually client-side is good about hiding errors from the user but still reports them. Thanks

Comment: @RishavKundu, should i type that in my code? Sorry i'm quite new to javascript.

Comment: And btw, right is an id for one of the faces of my cube. I want to change the face of the cube to an image.

Comment: @ScriptKitty, there are other unrelated errors. No problem with them. I'm sure.

Comment: @Ravi it will not work this way. You must either upload the image to the server first **or** use the File API like here http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/reading-files-using-the-html5-filereader-api

Comment: @RishavKundu, awesome dude. Thats exactly what i wanted. Can you please modify the code of the second example in the link you gave me and put it as an answer?

Comment: @Ravi it's ok. I'm feeling lazy :P You have the answer, and the link is present in the comments for future visitors, so it's ok....

Comment: @RishavKundu http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var input = document.getElementById('input');
  var container = document.getElementById('image-block');
  
  function onFilePicked(event) {
    var file = event.target.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    
    reader.onload = function(event) {
      var image = event.target.result;
     
      container.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + image + ')';
    };

    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }
  
  input.addEventListener('change', onFilePicked);
});
```

```css
#image-block {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="input">
<div id="image-block"></div>
```